# Registering an instance for navigation in Prism for Xamarin Forms with Unity

Tags: xamarin.forms, unity-container, prism

I'd like to register an instance of a view for navigation in Prism for Xamarin Forms with Unity and receive OnNavigatedTo on the associated view model when navigating to the instance. Registering an instance for navigation is not a supported registration out of the box so I created the following extension:

```
      public static void RegisterInstanceForNavigation<TView, TViewModel>(this IUnityContainer container, TView instance, string name = null)
        where TView : Page
        where TViewModel : class
      {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
        {
            name = typeof(TView).Name;
        }

        ViewModelLocationProvider.Register(typeof(TView).ToString(), typeof(TViewModel));
        PageNavigationRegistry.Register(name, typeof(TView));
        container.RegisterInstance(typeof(object), name, instance, new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
     }
```

In my app.xaml.cs, RegisterTypes, I register a page for navigation:

```
this.Container.RegisterInstanceForNavigation<AwesomeView, AwesomeViewModel>(
    new AwesomeView(),
    "seriouslyAnAwesomeView")
```

This seems to partially work. I can create an instance of a page, register it with a name and navigate to it. On the first navigation the corresponding view model's OnNavigatedTo from INavigationAware gets called; however, in subsequent navigation to the page, OnNavigatedTo is not called.

Is this registration valid? If so, why wouldn't OnNavigatedTo be called? If not, how can an instance be registered for navigation?

Comment: When you add a Prism Page, it will register it to the navigation automatically (on Xamarin.Forms)

Comment: @EstebanVerbel, I don't believe that Prism for Xamarin Forms registers a view for navigation automatically, you need to call RegisterTypeForNavigation. It does, however, now autowire the view model for the view so you don't have to include prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True" in your view XAML. However, could you care to explain a little more on how this might relate to registering and navigating to an instance (instance being important here)?

Comment: If on Visual Studio you go to Tools/Extensions and Updates, search for Prism Template Pack and install it, all this will be handled for you. Every time you add a new "Prism Page", a ViewModel will be created automatically as well as the registration on the App class on a override method called RegisterTypes()

Comment: Thanks, but this is a little more advanced than basic registration. When you call RegisterTypeForNavigation, the type is registered in the container, not an instance, nor is it registered as a singleton (container controlled lifetime). My aim is to register an instance. The reason is because the view that I'm registering is rather intensive to create and I only want to create it once. This is a view that the user will be navigating to and from frequently. When it's registered as a type and I navigate to and from, wouldnt a new one be created then destroyed? I'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: Here https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism you can find more information on how to install the Prism Template Pack. Also on this video Brian Lagunas goes over how to install it some of Prism "features" https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/XamarinShow/Prism-for-XamarinForms-with-Brian-Lagunas

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't a basic question on how to use Prism for Xamarin Forms.  I don't think that you understand what I'm asking, but I appreciate you trying to help though.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, you are right, it will probably create a new instance, but that can be easily tested. I am sure you can achieve that by using the default INavigation interface of Xamarin.Forms, but I'm not sure if it is possible with the Prism navigation class

Comment: Well first and foremost you shouldn't be using a singleton for a View Instance for a variety of reasons, which is why there is no RegisterInstance extension included with Prism. Basically though just understand you're going to open yourself up to a whole bunch of buggy behavior. As to your more specific question about why ```OnNavigatedTo``` isn't called, you would need to provide more information like a link to your application.

Comment: Could you explain at least a small sampling of the "variety of reasons" and "whole bunch of buggy behavior" that would be expected? I'd love to understand where you are coming from.

Comment: For one you're going to be keep the View/ViewModel in Memory even when it's not part of the Navigation Stack. Also consider the following:
ViewA -> ViewB -> ViewA... when you do something to ViewA the second time you could affect the state of the first ViewA instance.

Comment: @DanS. You're right for most; however, in my case, the view only allows for navigation back, it's modal, and is access frequently enough that recreating the view is less desirable than keeping it in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user presses the back button, Prism destroys the page and unsets the BindingContext. Prism only sets the BindingContext once at creation, if auto-wiring is enabled. Thus, the next time Prism navigates to your page, the binding context is `null` and `OnNaviagedTo` never gets called.

As mentioned in the comments above, keeping views around in memory is somewhat atypical behavior, and it appears that this behavior is not formally supported by Prism.

That being said, you can fix this issue fairly easily by resetting the binding context on the `Page`manually. Prism allows you to make your `Page` navigation aware like so:

```
public class MyReusablePage : ContentPage, INavigationAware
{
    ...

    public void OnNavigatingTo(NavigationParameters parameters)
    {
        if (this.BindingContext == null)
        {
            this.BindingContext = new MyReusablePageViewModel();
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Be wary that the new view model instance will NOT be identical to the one Prism originally created for you. If you need the view model instance to never change as well, you will need to disable auto-wiring (`AutoWireViewModel="False"` in XAML) and register your own singleton instance with Unity.